# How to display custom fields of taxonomy in field twig

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

In my content type for Event, I have an entity reference called Speakers which refers to a taxonomy called Team Members.   It's set to multiple so I can say which speakers belong to my event.    On the event detail page, I want to list the speakers out with all of their fields.

I have a field hook called field-field-speakers.html which lists all of the speakers.   I can't seem to get any of the fields within the taxonomy.  (ex: item.content.field_job_title ).   It doesn't display any content.

```
  {% for item in items %}

        <div class="member">

            <div class="name-box">
                <div class="name">

                 {{ item.content }}</div>
                <div class="position">{{ item.content.field_job_title }}</div>

            </div>
        </div>  


  {% endfor %}
```

How do I do this?   I think the answer might be in a View but not sure how to map it dynamically based on which event I am in.

Comment: Taxonomy is an entity, so you should have a custom View Mode for that, and change the field formatter setting on the Event (in the View Mode its using) to point to that view mode for rendering the term. Then they all become normal twig templates. Note, View Mode != Views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `item.content['#options'].entity.field_job_title.value` to get the value of the `job_title`field value, I don't know if this is the best way to do it.
So your code will be something like:

```
{% for item in items %}

  <div class="member">
    <div class="name-box">
      <div class="name">
        {{ item.content }}</div>
      <div class="position">{{ item.content['#options'].entity.field_job_title.value }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```